Electron forge wix maker & electron-updater
i've application that can run and update whenever new version released without no issue using squirrel build in electron forge. also it will update application automatically based on URL i've specified at latest.yml
Basically, i'm trying to achieve auto update mechanism on .msi wix installer (same just like squirel).
How can i do that ?

Manage to do it, you need to create a custom script at your
electron main.js

First it'll download your latest .exe


Then after downloaded already on user local PC, you need to silent install it.


After installation success, quit and restart your app. latest version will change if upgradedCode is match

